# Testing an after_commit hook in Rails 4 with transactional fixtures enabled

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rspec, rspec2

I've got a Rails 4 app and am using transactional fixtures, and want my after_commit hooks to trigger while running my integration specs.

Of course, no commits actually happens when you use transactional fixtures, so in Rails 3 there was this patch: https://gist.github.com/charleseff/1305285, and it was made into a gem: 'test_after_commit'

Rails 4 has changed the internals of active_record enough so that the Rails 3 patches cannot be ported.

Has anyone solved this issue in Rails 4?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved this by putting the following code in spec/support/helpers/test_after_commit.rb

```
require 'active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/transaction'
module ActiveRecord
  module ConnectionAdapters
    class SavepointTransaction < OpenTransaction
      def perform_commit_with_transactional_fixtures
        commit_records if number == 1
        perform_commit_without_transactional_fixtures        
      end

      alias_method_chain :perform_commit, :transactional_fixtures
    end
  end
end
```

https://gist.github.com/cmaitchison/5168104

Comment: just FYI: the monkey patch stopped working with Rails 4.2. since they changed the internals of ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::SavepointTransaction quite a lot.

Comment: Is there a solution for Rails 4.2?